# lim r(t) = L implies lim ||r(t)|| = ||L||

Tags: real-analysis, limits, normed-spaces, vector-analysis

The question is:

if $\lim_{t\rightarrow t_0}\vec r(t) =  \vec L$ show that $\lim_{t\rightarrow t_0} \|\vec r(t)\| = \|\vec L\|$

So here's where I am so far:

let $\vec r(t) = (f_1, f_2,...f_n)$ be such that the limit at a point $t_0$ is $\vec L$. Then by definition for all $\epsilon >0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $$\|\vec r(t) - \vec L\|<\epsilon$$ whenever $|t-t_0|<\delta$

I know I'm not very far but I don't know how to proceed, my initial thought was to mimic the proof of showing convergence implies absolute convergence, but don't seem to be getting anywhere. Please give only hints and no complete proofs as this is homework and i don't want to cheat.
Thanks

Comment: You can start by showing that [norm is a continuous function](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/96746/is-a-norm-a-continuous-function). For a continuous function you have $\lim_{t\to t_0} f(t) = f(t_0)$.

Answer (score 0):

By definition $\lim\limits_{t \to t_0} \vec{r}(t) = \vec{L} \Rightarrow$ given $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta_1>0$ such that;

$$|t-t_0|< \delta_1 \Rightarrow \|\vec{r}(t) - \vec{L}\|<\epsilon$$

You want to show that given $\epsilon$ there exists $\delta$ such that;

$$|t - t_0|< \delta \Rightarrow \left| \|\vec{r}(t)\|-\|\vec{L}\| \right|$$

Use reverse-triangle inequality i.e $\left| \|\vec{r}(t)\| - \|\vec{L}\| \right| \leq \|\vec{r}(t)- \vec{L}\|$. Therefore, choosing $\delta = \delta_1$ then we have;

$$|t-t_0| < \delta \Rightarrow \left| \|\vec{r}(t)\| - \|\vec{L}\| \right| \leq \|\vec{r}(t)-\vec{L}\| < \epsilon \Rightarrow \lim\limits_{t \to t_0} \|\vec{r}(t)\| = \|\vec{L}\|$$